# Limits of Liouville theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

We know by Liouville theorem that any bounded holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is constant.

I was wondering if I could find an holomorphic function $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}_- \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ which is bounded but not constant.
Also can we expand this to any half-line of the complex plane ?

Comment: Look up “Riemann mapping theorem” – $\Bbb C  \setminus {\Bbb R}_-$ can be conformally mapped to the unit disk.

Comment: Koebe function $z/(z-1)^2=\sum nz^n$ sends the unit disc confirmally onto the plane minus the part of the negative half line starting at $-1/4$, so its inverse is holomorphic and sends that domain onto the unit disc; shifts and rotations can give you any half line; the plane minus any finite or countable set of points with no accumulation point satisfy Liouville but once the boundary has an arc you can find such as above

Comment: you should be able to do this explicitly by using a choice of logarithm, e.g. $\exp\Big(i \cdot \text{log}(z)\Big)$, since $\text{log}(z)$ sends $z$ to points in a horizontal strip (i.e. bounded imaginary component but unbounded reals) and multiplication by $i$ sends this to a vertical strip